# "increment of read-only variable" error for non-const local member used in a lambda in constructor's body

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to create a class where in the constructor's body, a local member variable is initialized and reused in a lambda which is also initialized directly in the constructor's body. A very simple version of this looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class TestClass {
    public:
    TestClass()
    {
        auto localMember = 0;
        const auto incrementAndDisplay = [localMember] {
            localMember++;
            std::cout << "Member value is now increased to: " << localMember << std::endl;
        };

        incrementAndDisplay();
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestClass testClass;
    return 0;
}
```

However, this code does not compile. GCC throws the following error message for the line where the local member is modified:

```
main.cpp:9:13: error: increment of read-only variable ‘localMember’
    9 |             localMember++;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am confused by this error message, because I never labeled this variable to be `const` and can modify it outside the lambda without any problems. However, if I declare `localMember` as a class member, the code will compile without any problems.
My best guess at this point is that the lambda cannot seem to access the member "correctly" because it is only a temporary value and might be discarded later. However, I might be completely wrong about that.
The question is: Is there a way to use the variable in a lambda, without making it a class member? And if that is not possible, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are capturing the constructor's local variable by value.

Lambdas are implicitly immutable, and the captured `localMember` is a member variable of your lambda (which you've even specified to be `const`). In order to make it mutable, you need to remove `const` and add `mutable`:

```cpp
/*const*/ auto incrementAndDisplay = [localMember]() mutable {
  ^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^
  remove                                   |          add
                                           |
                  copy of the variable defined in the surrounding function
```

If you actually wanted to increase the value of the variable `localMember` that you defined *outside* of the lambda, you need to capture it by reference:

```cpp
auto incrementAndDisplay = [&localMember] {
//                          ^
//                  capture by reference
```

Comment: That is incredibly helpful to know. Thank you!